# How can i add an id to the_post_thumbnail()?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to handle clicks on my fotorama galery (for redirect to another pages). For that I need to give an id for each image/thumbnail.. I'm using the next code but it is not working.

```
$atbrthumb = array(
    'id' => 'idexample',
);
$image = the_post_thumbnail( $size , $atbrthumb );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this. Here is the link to [refer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

```
the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'image-class', 'title' => 'Feature image','id' => 'idexample']);
```

Comment: @ErikO.M. Please Upvote too. So that it might be useful to others